# When I use storm, if one server crashed(e.g. shutdown), will the topology process the tuple once processed on the host again

Tags: apache-storm, topology

For example, tuple A is now processing on Server B. Suddenly, server B is shut down by my crazy colleague. Will the topology process tuple A again on another server?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable fault-tolerance (and the tuple was not acked), than yes.

What API are you using? For low-level API, you enable fault-tolerance by assigning IDs to the tuples you emit in your spouts.

See https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html for more details.

For Trident, it depend what spout you are using: https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/Trident-spouts.html